# port 80 is closed. how to open it

Tags: apache, localhost, portforwarding

I am trying to make my Apache server publicly accessible. I opened port 80 in my router and my windows firewall , It didn't work. my router ISP is disabled. When I check port , i find it closed. THIS IS MY APACHE CONFIGURATION (WHAT I CHANGED IN MY HTTPD FILE:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Is there any thing i should to solve this problem

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: This question does not apply to SO.

Comment: Is Apache accessible from localhost? If you introduced an error in the config, that would prevent it from starting at all.

Comment: yes it's accessible from my localhost and from other devices in my network , I want to make it accessible from outside

Comment: Then triple check your router configuration. Also check your ISP is not blocking certain ports. I know some do, so even if you forward the port 80 on your router, it has no effect as it's blocked at a higher level.

Comment: ISP is disabled

Comment: ISP = Internet Service Provider, I'd rather not disable that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure port forwarding on your router in order to get all incoming traffic redirected to your local web server

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're using a static IP address when you added your pc server in your modem and you're using both TCP/UDP as an additional action to take care that we have connection access to all

Also be sure you're using Nat Port forwarding **Not** Port Mapping 
and added your LAN IP not *WAN IP*

Some routers requires you to **check** a **box** to **Enable** Port forwarding after adding it
and I suggest you to check that now maybe you haven't noticed

Try programming a simple TCP or UDP server for open connection/listening test
otherwise try search and get one at [GitHub](https://github.com) or [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net) then check port online with your Host IP Address while (listening)

> *But* also take caution that you testing port for your specific protocol

If port is opened then the problem in your configuration and you have to re-read it backwards carefully

Else..then the problem in your router port forwarding configuration *not* in apache
and you have to check Lan-IP/Port-Start/End/Enabled etc..

If still having problems then please be more specific in your question and try

- attaching screenshot of your port settings
- Post your configuration
- If you tried specific open source server program will be helpful to post the code

At the end i advice you to use Client/Server opensource script or program with a friend remotely
instead of checking online and that also if you have troubles finding one.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this conf:

```
Name: local server
App name: HTTP
IP Address: 192.168.1.10 #your local server ip.
Port:
    Start: 80
    End: 80
Traffic Type: TCP
```